# Sorting a parent multidimensional array by the values it contains in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, time

I am creating a website for a basketball team and I want to display the team schedule on a table that is sorted by the start date of the game. I have an array called $games in which another array lies with key pairs of `home` `away` and `time`.

Here is the code used to create the following array. I am indexing this info from an API.

```
$index = 0;
$games = array(); 

 for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($response[$index]); $i++) {  
    array_push($games, array("home" => $response[$index]['home']['name'], "away" => $response[$index]['away']['name'], "time" => $response[$index]['start_at'])); 
  }
  $index +=1;
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2015-01-27 19:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2017-02-24 19:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2016-12-02 19:00:00
        )
)
```

I want the parent index to be sorted by the child value of time in the array. In the end I would like the array to look like this.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2017-02-24 19:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2016-12-02 19:00:00
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2015-01-27 19:00:00
        )
)
```

I have looked into the `array_multisort()` function, but cannot find a function to sort the actual parent, just the keys within the array. I also looked at `asort()` but encountered the same problem.

Any help is extremely appreciated!

-Kelton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/758055)

```
<?php
$game=Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            "home" => "School1",
           "away" => "School2",
            "time" => "2015-01-27 19:00:00"
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            "home" => "School1",
            "away" => "School2",
            "time"=> "2017-02-24 19:00:00"
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            "home" => "School1",
            "away" => "School2",
            "time" => "2016-12-02 19:00:00"
        )
);
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (strtotime($a["time"]) == strtotime($b["time"])) 
    {
       return 0;
    }
    return ($a["time"] > $b["time"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($game, "cmp");
print_r($game);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2017-02-24 19:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2016-12-02 19:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [home] => School1
            [away] => School2
            [time] => 2015-01-27 19:00:00
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is usort. You would do something such as:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   if($a['time'] < $b['time']) {
      return 1; 
   } else if ($a['time'] === $b['time']) {
      return 0; 
   }
   else {
     return -1; 
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### This solution is simpler than all other solutions on the page!

While I'll assume all of these `usort()` answers provide the correct result, the problem is they all failed to identify the simplest solution...

You can avoid a "user-defined comparison function" if you just declare your `time` element as the first element of each subarray.  Using `rsort()` will be the most efficient way to handle your sorting task:

The Setup (something like this...)

```
foreach($response[$index] as $a){    
    $games[]=['time'=>$a['start_at'],'home'=>$a['home']['name'],'away'=>$a['away']['name']];
}
```

This will generate an array like this:

```
$game=[
    ["time"=>"2015-01-27 19:00:00","home"=>"School1","away"=>"School2"],
    ["time"=>"2017-02-24 19:00:00","home"=>"School1","away"=>"School2"],
    ["time"=>"2016-12-02 19:00:00","home"=>"School1","away"=>"School2"],
];
```

Then your condition-less sorting solution is:

```
rsort($game);  // sort DESC
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ea7dd42e9c847784d471b24a65d85b9ced6433e)

Output (using `var_export($game);`):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'time' => '2017-02-24 19:00:00',
    'home' => 'School1',
    'away' => 'School2',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'time' => '2016-12-02 19:00:00',
    'home' => 'School1',
    'away' => 'School2',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'time' => '2015-01-27 19:00:00',
    'home' => 'School1',
    'away' => 'School2',
  ),
)
```